# Reflections is looking for package in my libraries

Tags: java, api

The library Reflections library for the package I specified looks for such a package in my libraries, but not in my project, why?

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("net.test");
System.out.println(reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Plugin.class));
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, your question does not give much clarity of your problem.

Comment: I want to find all classes with @Plugin annotation in the given package. But for some reason, the library is looking for this package in my libraries, but not in the given package